# Wordpress: How or where I can customize this (wp-block-latest-comments__comment-meta)?

Tags: wordpress

The WP block (wp-block-latest-comments__comment-meta) has been coded with a fixed design, which cannot be customized in the editor, admin area, or customizer. It only allows for displaying the avatar, date, excerpt, and the number of comments. The problem is that I want to add a line break between the meta author and the meta data ("Author" on "Title name") to improve readability. Where can I find the code snippet for wp-block-latest-comments__comment-meta?

I'm looking forward to your clever solutions and informative tips.

Comment: find the theme style.css,mostly there, else write a child theme on your wp and fix it in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, customize in Wordpress Customizer of part 'your adjustments for
Additional CSS':

```
.wp-block-latest-comments__comment-author::after {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}
```